# How can I get/create an instance of an object on Simple Injector container depending on the asp.net web api 2 session?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, simple-injector

I have an asp.net web api 2 project in which I register a singleton LoginData

```
containerLocal.RegisterSingleton<ILoginData>(
    () => new LoginData { LanguageCode = null, UserCode = null });
```

What I want to do is when a user log in to the app I register an instance of that Login data in my container

```
var loginData = AppContainer.Container.GetInstance<ILoginData>();

loginData.UserCode = userData.Username;
loginData.LanguageCode = "es";
```

and then, on whatever controller get that instance of user to perform any operation

my problem is that when I try to make a get request from 2 different browsers I get the last instance of Login data created in the app instead of the instance with the correct user

```
[Route("stock/menu")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Menu()
{
    var loginData = AppContainer.Container.GetInstance<ILoginData>();
    return Ok(loginData);
}
```

example:

- Login in chrome browser with username 'foo'
- Make get request on InventarioMenu in chrome (gets LoginData with user 'foo')
- Login in firefox browser with username 'bar'
- Make get request on InventarioMenu in firefox (gets LoginData with user 'bar')
- Make get request on InventarioMenu in chrome (gets LoginData with user 'bar')

Comment: I know i'm creating the instance on the singleton register, but how can I register multiple instances on the container of those users and get them

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this. A possible solution is to make an `ILoginData` implementation that stores information in a Session:

```cs
public sealed class SessionLoginData : ILoginData
{
    public string UserCode
    {
        get { (string)this.Session[nameof(UserCode)]; }
        set { this.Session[nameof(UserCode)] = value; }
    }

    public string LanguageCode
    {
        get { (string)this.Session[nameof(LanguageCode)]; }
        set { this.Session[nameof(LanguageCode)] = value; }
    }

    private HttpSessionState Session => HttpContext.Current.Session;
}
```

Since this class itself contains no state (but delegates that to the `HttpContext.Session`), this implementation can be registered as singleton:

```cs
container.RegisterSingleton<ILoginData, SessionLoginData>();
```